# Prompting re-consent while signing in with OpenID Connect

Tags: openid, google-signin, openid-connect, google-openid

I am facing a problem that each time user logs in with OpenID Connect, user is presented with consent screen (scope authorization screen).

When I read the documentation it says

> You can prompt the user to re-authorize your app by adding the
>   prompt=consent parameter to the authentication request. When
>   prompt=consent is included, the consent screen is displayed every time
>   the user logs into your app. For this reason, include prompt=consent
>   only when necessary.
>
> If no value is specified and the user has not previously authorized
>   access, then the user is shown a consent screen.

But even if I pass empty value, this screen comes every time.

Comment: Can you post your request so I can see all the parameters? You can hide (xx it) the client id and redirect uri. Most likely you are asking for offline access in every request.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should be passing is "prompt=none". In this case, if the user has a valid login session and the user has already given consent to the application, then user will see no page and will be logged into the application automatically. 
If there is no valid session or the application doesn't has the consent, then still user shouldn't see a consent or login page, but the application should receive and error.

Comment: As I understand it, this is incorrect. `prompt=none` is for silent authentication.https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/silent-authentication

Comment: No, its the same. Silent authentication is a side effect of prompt=none when user already has an active session. This was a trick used by implicit flow clients to get new access tokens, but never was a standard. However, silent authentication will not have a future since the implicit flow itself will be deprecated.